# The autoloader expected class [...] to be defined in file

Tags: symfony

I'm new to Symfony 3. I try to resolve a problem with my two controllers.
When I execute the indexAction function I've got this error :

> The autoloader expected class "Arcturus\GeomancieBundle\Controller\TirageController" to be defined in file "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/geomancie2/geomancie/vendor/composer/../../src/Arcturus/GeomancieBundle/Controller/TirageController.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

I've found that can be a typo in a class...but did'nt find anything wrong.

Here's my two controllers :

DefaultController.php

```
<?php

namespace Arcturus\GeomancieBundle\Controller;
namespace Arcturus\GeomancieBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Form;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Arcturus\GeomancieBundle\Entity;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request) {
        $tirage = new Tirage();
        $formTirage = $this->createFormBuilder($tirage)->getForm();

        // Si le formulaire a été soumis

        $formTirage->handleRequest($request);

        if ($formTirage->isSubmitted() && $formTirage->isValid()) {
            $tirage = $formTirage->all();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('arcturus_geomancie_tirage', $tirage);
        }

        // Si le formulaire n'a pas été soumis

        return $this->render('ArcturusGeomancieBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
           'form' => $formTirage->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

TirageController.php

```
<?php

namespace Arcturus\GeomancieBundle\Controller;
namespace Arcturus\GeomancieBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class TirageController extends Controller
{
    public function afficherTirageAction(Tirage $tirage)
    {
        // On compte le nombre de points dans chaque chaîne
        $nb_dot_l1 = $this->nbDot($tirage->getLigne1());
        $nb_dot_l2 = $this->nbDot($tirage->getLigne2());
        $nb_dot_l3 = $this->nbDot($tirage->getLigne3());
        $nb_dot_l4 = $this->nbDot($tirage->getLigne4());

        // On vérifie que les 4 chaînes contriennent au moins 1 point
        if ($nb_dot_l1 == 0 or $nb_dot_l2 == 0 or $nb_dot_l3 == 0 or $nb_dot_l4 == 0) {
            // On renvoie sur une page d'erreur
            $this->renderView('@ArcturusGeomancie/Default/erreur_tirage.html.twig');
        }

        // On charge les lignes dans un tableau paire/impaire
        $tab_dots_lines = $this->dots_to_array($nb_dot_l1, $nb_dot_l2, $nb_dot_l3, $nb_dot_l4);
        // On garde ce format pour dessiner la figure
        $data['dessin'] = $tab_dots_lines;
        // On récupère le nom de la figure
        $data['figure'] = $this->get_figure($tab_dots_lines);
        // On récupère l'analyse associée
        $data['analyse'] = $this->get_analysis($data['figure']);

        $this->renderView('@ArcturusGeomancie/Default/tirage.html.twig', $data);
    }
[...]
```

Tirage.php (Entity)

```
<?php

class Tirage
{
    private $ligne1;
    private $ligne2;
    private $ligne3;
    private $ligne4;

    public function getLigne1()
    {
        return $this->ligne1;
    }

    public function getLigne2()
    {
        return $this->ligne2;
    }

    public function getLigne3()
    {
        return $this->ligne3;
    }

    public function getLigne4()
    {
        return $this->ligne4;
    }
}

?>
```

And my directory tree :

[image]

Could anyone help me to find my error ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a problem with namespaces in your files.

Remove line

```
namespace Arcturus\GeomancieBundle\Entity;
```

from DefaultController.php and TirageController.php, and put it in Tirage.php

```
<?php

namespace Arcturus\GeomancieBundle\Entity;

class Tirage
{
```

You can read more about namespaces here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: Thank you, now I've got : Class Arcturus\GeomancieBundle\Controller\Tirage does not exist. Any idea ?

Comment: CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception ReflectionException: "Class Arcturus\GeomancieBundle\Controller\Tirage does not exist" at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/geomancie2/geomancie/vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/EventListener/ParamConverterListener.php line 83

Comment: your method afficherTirageAction() takes one parameter - instance of the class Arcturus\GeomancieBundle\Entity\Tirage <br>

but you are missing use statement for that class, you should put statement  'use Arcturus\GeomancieBundle\Entity\Tirage;'  in the  TirageController.php

 ... more info at: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Answer (score 4):

## For those using [[image]phpstorm](/questions/tagged/phpstorm)

Here is a neat trick. Mark the *src* directory as "Sources Root", this way whenever a file is created within your *src* directory, it'll automatically add the correct namespace.

This will help avoid the error:

> The autoloader expected class […] to be defined in file

Here is an image showing how to mark your directory as "Sources Root".

[image: mark directory as sources root]

Comment: What menu option did you click to get the drop-down you show here?  Perhaps more importantly, how did you get phpStorm to 'know' about your directory structure on the server?

Comment: @HowardBrown right click on the `src` directory. What do you mean by "directory structure on the *server*"?

Answer (score 2):

Your namespaces are a bit out, you just put one in put class.

The controller should have the single namespace of;

```
namespace Arcturus\GeomancieBundle\Controller;
```

and your entity should have the namespace of;

```
namespace Arcturus\GeomancieBundle\Entity;
```

Also, have you set your routing up properly?
If you are using annotations, something like (in app/config/routing.php);

```
app:
    resource: "@GeomancieBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation
```

or

```
my_route:
    path: /my-url
    defaults:   {_controller: ArcturusGeomancieBundle:Tirage:afficherTirage }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this same error for a  different problem. 
I moved one folder from Appbundle/controller/Myfolder to Appbundle/Myfolder. 
After that i constantly got that error. 
Im using git and server version wasnt matching the local version so I couldn't see there was a duplicated folder in the server because the auto-upload didnt delete

So updating/syncronizing manually your server might help with this error if the upload fails on deleting files.